# How to export a terrain from Unity to Blender?

Tags: unity, blender, terrain, import, export

I'm trying to make an environment for my scene that consists animations and other objects such as trees.

Making a terrain in Unity seem to be a lot easier than in Blender, so I want to export that environment which I've made in Unity to Blender. How can I do this?

Comment: There are a few assets that can do things like this in the unity asset store. I am not sure if one can export everything including animations etc. But you can check by searching for `FBX Exporter` in the asset store.

Comment: @schneebuzz Found it but dang it costs (I understand that), if something wouldn't work and I can't get a refund, that wouldn't be very fun. Thanks for the answer though, might try it in the future.